# Notepad++: How to bulk add syntax in the start of a row (regular expressions)

Tags: notepad++, regex

Assuming I have a row with text, and I want to add another text in the very end of the original text like this:

```
OldTextNewText
```

I can do it this way:

1. Mouse-select lines X through Y
2. CTRL + F
3. Select "regular expression" (under "Search mode")
4. For Find what, type `(.*)`
5. For Replace with, `\1xyz` to paste syntax in row's end.
6. Click the "In selection" checkbox, and do the change.

### My question:

How could I do the opposite process? i.e:

```
NewTextOldText
```

Comment: As worded, your question is unclear.  Consider posting a before and after sample with several lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting anything in the line with a RegEx,
just replace `^` with your `NewText` at the beginning or
replace `$` with your `NewText`at the end.

**Select:** Select Text with Mouse or [shift]+[Cursor-UP]/[Cursor-Down]
**[Ctrl]+F**
**Find:** `^`  or `$`
**Replace:** NewText
Select Radiobutton Regular Expression
Check mark in selection

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this works.

**Select**: SelectedText 

**Find**: (.*) 

**Replace**: xyz\1

**Result**: xyxSelectedText

Comment: @Benia If I didn't understand the question, please clarify.